# Cannot access value of object property

Tags: javascript

I am looping though an object to retrieve some properties but for some reason I cannot access the value of a nested object property.

This is my looping function:

```
  parseContacts = (contacts) => {
    return contacts.map(contact => {
      let parsedContact = {};
      Object.keys(contact).forEach(key => {
        if (key === 'givenName') {
          parsedContact.firstName = contact[key];
        } if (key === 'familyName') {
          parsedContact.surname = contact[key];
        } if (key === 'phoneNumbers') {
          parsedContact.phoneNumber = contact[key][0].number;
        }
      })
      return parsedContact;
    })
  }
```

`firstName` and `surname` work fine, but in the last if statement I get `undefined`. the property with key `phoneNumbers` it is an array of objects, and this is item `0` in the array:

```
{id: "302", label: "mobile", number: "+44 7X7X 50XX72"}
```

When I use this code instead:

```
} if (key === 'phoneNumbers') {
          parsedContact.phoneNumber = contact[key][0];
        }
```

without `.number` on the end I get the whole object back fine, I just can't get back *only* the `number` property from the object.

### Update

On closer inspection, the array which has over 800 large objects in, some of the lengths of the `phoneNumbers` arrays were `0` so the property did not exist. This was causing the whole function to fail. Thanks for the comments below.

My solution was to add to the if statement:

```
if (key === 'phoneNumbers' && contact[key].length)
```

Comment: Are there any of the objects in `contacts` have an empty `phoneNumbers` array? Is the property `number` or `numbers`? Because, you have written "*without `.numbers` on the end I get the whole object back fine*"

Comment: Can you paste your dataset, for me it is working fine.

Comment: could you post the data on which you loop through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent the empty phoneNumbers array issue like this:

```
contact[key] && contact[key].length ? contact[key][0].number : ''
```

```js
const parseContacts = contacts => {
    return contacts.map(contact => {
      let parsedContact = {}
      Object.keys(contact).forEach(key => {
        switch (key) {
          case 'givenName':
            parsedContact.firstName = contact[key]
            break
          case 'familyName':
            parsedContact.surname = contact[key]
            break
          case 'phoneNumbers':
            parsedContact.phoneNumber = contact[key] && contact[key].length ? contact[key][0].number : ''
        }
      })
      return parsedContact
    })
}
  
const contacts = []

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   contacts.push({
      givenName: faker.name.firstName(),
      familyName: faker.name.lastName(),
      phoneNumbers: [
        {
         id: faker.random.uuid(),
         label: 'mobile',
         number: faker.phone.phoneNumber()
        }, {
         id: faker.random.uuid(),
         label: 'mobile',
         number: faker.phone.phoneNumber()
        }
      ]
   })
}

 contacts.push({
    givenName: faker.name.firstName(),
    familyName: faker.name.lastName(),
    phoneNumbers: []
 })
 
  contacts.push({
    givenName: faker.name.firstName(),
    familyName: faker.name.lastName(),
    phoneNumbers: null
 })

console.log('RESULT ' + JSON.stringify(parseContacts(contacts)))
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Marak/faker.js/master/examples/browser/js/faker.js"></script>
```